# How to use xpath locator in Cypress with TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, xpath, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Initially, xpath plug-in was working good with my cypress project. Installed typescript plugin and  Moved from javascript to Typescript. Now It started throwing an error on xpath

```
Property 'xpath' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.ts(2339)
```

[image]

Please suggest , how to use xpath with typescript in Cypress project ?  `cypress-xpath": "^1.6.2",` is included in package.json

package.json file is as below:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.17.8",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.0",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this to work you have to add this in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress", "cypress-xpath"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding reference types on top of the file where you are using will resolve the issue

```
/// <reference types="cypress-xpath" />
```